# sparse matrix-matrix / matrix-vector multiplication c++

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, eigen3

I'm using eigen3 package in c++ to do some linear algebra, but one part of the code which includes some matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplications takes too long. my matrices and vectors are pretty big (order 20kx20k) but some are sparse. what I read from eigen documentation, it is designed to be working efficiently with sparse matrices. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how I can improve it. Would appreciate any help.
Here is part of the code; we have n input data for which we calculate 'k' from a function and for each point we need to find a 'mean' value defined in the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic)
for (unsigned long n = 0; n < nNew; n++) {
  SparseVector<double> kJ(totalJ);
  double k = something; #calculates using a function
  for(int i=0; i<totalJ; i++) {
      double covTmp = xxx; #calculates using a function
      kJ.insert(i) = covTmp;
  }

  SparseVector<double> CJikJ(totalJ);
  CJikJ = CJi * kJ;

  double kJTCJikJ = kJ.transpose().dot(CJikJ);
  double mu = 1. / (k - kJTCJikJ);

  SparseVector<double> mJ(totalJ);
  mJ= -mu * CJikJ;

  SparseMatrix<double> MJi(totalJ, totalJ);
  MJi = CJ - kJ*kJ.transpose()*mu / (1. + mu * kJTCJikJ);

  SparseMatrix<double> VNGJMJiGJTi(nstars, nstars);
  VNGJMJiGJTi = invertMatrix(VN + GJ * (MJi * GJT), nstars);

  SparseMatrix<double> RJi(totalJ, totalJ);
  RJi = MJi - MJi * GJT * (VNGJMJiGJTi) * (GJ * MJi); ## this line takes too long
  RJi.prune(prunelim);

  SparseVector<double> RJimJ;
  RJimJ = RJi*mJ;


  double alpha = mu - mJ.dot(RJimJ);
  double beta = AN.dot((VNi * GJ) * RJimJ);
  double mean = -beta / alpha;

      outfile << setprecision(8) << newposm[n][0] << ", " << newposm[n][1] << ", " << newposm[n][2] << ", " << alpha << ", " << beta << ", " << mean << ", " << variance << "\n";
  if(params.vb) {
    cout << setprecision(8) << "# l, b, dist, alpha, beta, mean, var" << endl;
    cout << setprecision(8) << newposm[n][0] << ", " << newposm[n][1] << ", " << newposm[n][2] << ", " << alpha << ", " << beta << ", " << mean << ", " << variance << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: How fast do you expect?

Comment: @kangshiyin: it is taking forever now! I have a matrix inversion before this step which is done in ~2 hours but this part is too long; it's been running for 4 days now (for n=1000 and with 10 cores in parallel)

Comment: I also have memory issue; for some nodes I receive core dump...

Comment: try debug with small matrix size; `20k` is a large enough size that you don't need to use `#pragma omp parallel for`. Eigen calculate the expressions in parallel.

Comment: @kangshiyin: thanks for your reply. I don't use  `#pragma omp parallel for` to calculate expressions in parallel but it's used to do these calculations for 1000 points in parallel. Another words; if I want to do this calculation for only 1 point (still using 20K matrix size) I don't need the omp.

Comment: I mean you can delete the first line and your code can still utilize the multiple cores in your CPU. Eigen will compute the expressions in parallel. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html

Comment: btw where's the '1000 points' from? It seems you still have some way to go to clearly describe your question.

Comment: @kangshiyin: sorry if I didn't describe the problem clearly... Here is the problem:

Comment: Assume I don't have the omp line; the goal is to calculate the 'mean' which is defined at the end of the code for which we need to solve the matrix multiplication, etc.. this 'mean' is calculated for one point but we want to calculate it for 1000 different points; that's why I added the omp parallel line (k is defined differently based on every new point). these points are read as the input data.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. Maybe this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You almost never need to invert an matrix. It's slow and less accurate.  How sparse is your matrix?  What is the ratio of non zeros to the matrix size (nnz/n^2)?  It's pretty easy to write your own scalar `matrix*matrix` and `matrix*vector` code using compressed row storage.  You might want to back up and do this by hand so you know what's going on.  Reinventing the wheel even if it's not totally round can teach you a lot.